# UIButton's animating images doesn't show swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview, uibutton

This is driving me nuts. I've spent two days following all documentation I can find on how to animate `UIImageview`. But **no animating images on the `UIButton` are shown** when I run the app and code (called in `viewDidLoad`).

The last if-statement even prints out "yes, it running". But nothing is shown in the simulator or on device.

**Update:** Have added the `func setImage(_ image: UIImage?, for state: UIControlState):` function. Now the first images loads and is shown, but still no animating...

Have also tried giving the button a separate `Outlet` - same result... 
I'm really stuck now.

```
        var Cowboy:[UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "Cowboy__000")!, UIImage(named: "Cowboy__001")!,UIImage(named: "Cowboy__002")!,UIImage(named: "Cowboy__003")!,UIImage(named: "Cowboy__004")!,UIImage(named: "Cowboy__005")!,UIImage(named: "Cowboy__006")!,UIImage(named: "Cowboy__007")!,UIImage(named: "Cowboy__008")!, UIImage(named: "Cowboy__009")!]

        var currentAnimationImages = [UIImage]

        for i in 0..<Cowboy.count {

            currentAnimationImages.append(Cowboy[i])

        }

        //buttons stored in outlet collection
        print("currentAnimationImages", currentAnimationImages) //the array contains the images!
        buttons[0].setImage(currentAnimationImages.first, for: .normal) //is shown
        //nothing happens...
        buttons[0].imageView!.animationImages = currentAnimationImages
        buttons[0].imageView!.animationDuration = 0.2
        buttons[0].imageView!.animationRepeatCount = 10
        buttons[0].imageView!.startAnimating()
            if buttons[0].imageView!.isAnimating == true {
            print("yes, running") //this is printed out!
            } else {
            print("no, not running")
            }
```

All help is needed and appreciated.

Comment: may be all the images are same

Comment: is `buttons` an IBOutletCollection?  is it wired up in your storyboard or xib file?

Comment: @Vinodh they are a set of images which together create an animation.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Yes, they wired up via storyboard.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann  But the same thing happens if I wire them up separately, with separate `Outlets`

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `func setImage(_ image: UIImage?, for state: UIControlState):` get the image to show before animating it.

For example:

```
buttons[0]. setImage(currentAnimationImages[0], forState: .Normal)
// Now you can start animating
buttons[0].imageView!.animationImages = currentAnimationImages
buttons[0].imageView!.animationDuration = 0.2
buttons[0].imageView!.animationRepeatCount = 10
buttons[0].imageView!.startAnimating()
```

Comment: Try increasing `animationDuration` to 1.0

Comment: Try adding `.png` or whatever your file extension is at the end of every image's name. For example `UIImage(named: "Cowboy__000.png")!`